# Django cors error even after installing cors-headers

Tags: python, django, cors, django-cors-headers

My python view is using requests, like so:

```
r = requests.post(url, params=data, headers=header)
print r.url
return HttpResponse(r)
```

The object is POSTED to a redirect URL.  When the URL is called, all activity stops in the browser and this error is thrown:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://<website>.com. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I have already installed django-cors-headers with the following line added in the settings.py:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Why am I still getting the error?

Comment: what does posted to a redirect url mean?

Comment: I am sending a POST request and the response is redirectio

Comment: Are you trying to circumvent CORS by creating a view on your server that picks up a foreign resource and presents it as local?  Is the error message coming from the browser accessing your view, or does the view create an error when posting? If the post is returning a 302 response you should perhaps use Django's `HttpResponseRedirect`? Have you checked that the preflight requests are correct/happening?

Comment: The message is coming in the browser's console. On using HttpResponseRedirect, I get : 'Response' object has no attribute 'find'.

Comment: The requests are correct, if I take the URL of the request with the parameters and paste it directly in the browser, it does work.

Comment: That it works in the browser doesn't tell us much, at all. You need to add more information to this question, it's impossible to guess what you've done wrong based on your description (it's quite close to "my car won't start, but I can get this other car to start" :-). My guess would be that you just don't know how CORS is supposed to work (like what a preflight request is and where CORS should be applied) and/or you're lacking basic Django skills (like understanding HttpResponseRedirect).  I'm afraid this isn't a good forum for tutorials on either...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the correct CORS middleware and more importantly its sequence and its allowed methods too.
Also, make sure it's listed in your installed_apps setting.